# How to cancel timer in newOrderFragment from utilmethod.java class when I'm logged out from homeActivity in Android

Tags: android, timer, fragment, logout

When I log out from the homeactivity, it shows fragment processing through timer inside it.
I want to cancel the timer from utilmethod java class where logOutalertDialog exits.
I would like that when I press "yes" timer should stop.

Comment: plz help me guyz i want your help

Answer (score 0):

Get the timer instance and in the logout method, before navigating, cancel the timer. Basically, you will have to maintain the timer instance and cancel it before logging out.
Show some code as well, then this community can answer your query in a much better way